# Undefined method "encoding" in http_poller logstash config

Tags: logstash, zabbix

I'm trying to use the logstash `http_poller` plug-in to pull data from a Zabbix "rest" endpoint.  I'm getting the following error:

> Error: undefined method `encoding' for #<Hash:0x370283f5>

Here's my config:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    interval => 15
    codec => "json"
    urls => {
      zab => {
        url => "http://my_zabbbix_server/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php"
        method => post
        headers => {
          "content-type" => "application/json"
        }
        body => {
          jsonrpc => "2.0"
          method => "user.login"
          params => {
            user => "myusername"
            password => "ermagerd"
            }
          id => 1
        }
        #auth => null
      }
    }
  }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

}

If anyone could shed some light on what is not correct or missing from my configuration that would be great. Yeah.

Comment: Note that it's not REST, it's JSON-RPC. I don't know what's wrong with your setup, but what's that hashmark in front of "auth"? Also, what's that trailing closing curly brace?

Comment: @Richlv The hash is supposed to be a comment. The extra squirrely brace is probably a copy/paste error I made when posting. I'll have to check tomorrow when I am back at work.

Comment: I've never seen `body` being used in the URL configuration of the `http_poller` input plugin. Can you run logstash with the `--debug` flag and show the output you get?